# In-place text editing component for Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any good in-place editing component that makes use of the new Twitter Bootstrap 3 style guideline?

I'm looking for any jQuery [..] plugin that does something like:

1. There is a line (or block) of text
2. when hovered by the mouse, a small symbol appears, saying 'you can edit me!'
3. on click, the text field (or block) vanishes, making place for an appropriately sized text input or textfield
4. saves on enter (or ctrl+enter)

As said, this component should conform the Bootstrap 3 style, preferably making use of bootstrap's `less` support.

Answer (score 4):

`x-editable` is the dam good solution for inplace editing. Yeah it does support bootstrap3.

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html?c=popup

For "you can edit me!" you can write custom callback like following:

```
$(".editable").on "hover",  ->
  alert "you can edit me!"
```

Comment: Project is currently frozen and contains a lot of issues that no one is paying any attention. See the author [notice](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable).

Comment: @RuiMarques Looks like its back under development. Files are updated recently and also the status on github says "Actively maintained"